# hibernate update only some fields

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

In some cases I want to update only one collumn, but I don't want to get the object from the data base and I only have it's ID and the value I want to update.

As the other values are null, the hibernate are updating then as null.
I wonder some criteria to erase the other columns from the update.

I read about dynamic-update=true and its only exclude the unmodified properties. But the nulls are still there at my update.

Does anyone have any idea?
Thanks!
Felipe

Comment: I have asked myself the same thing and vote to reopen. Lets say that I just want to update the status of an object but left all the other fields unchanged. The Hibernate equivalent to the SQL "UPDATE table SET status=:status WHERE id = :id"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to get the object from the database, change the value and save it. If you don't want that, you have to write your own query.